# Getting value from class in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to get Operation Message from cargo webservice.

After I fill the inside of $myArr array, i am sending a request to web service like this;

```
    $result = $client->queryShipment($myArr);   // it asks to web server whether cargo exist or not
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";
```

And then the PHP result is;

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["ShippingDeliveryVO"]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (5) {
    ["outFlag"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["outResult"]=>
    string(11) "Success"
    ["count"]=>
    int(1)
    ["senderCustId"]=>
    int(1012883)
    ["shippingDeliveryDetailVO"]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (6) {
      ["cargoKey"]=>
      string(12) "645558612997"
      ["invoiceKey"]=>
      string(10) "41db64ff4f"
      ["jobId"]=>
      int(4006477)
      ["operationCode"]=>
      int(0)
      ["operationMessage"]=>
      string(25) "There is no  process with cargo."
      ["operationStatus"]=>
      string(3) "NOP"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get only operationMessage value from my $result. How can i do that?

Comment: tries json_decode($result,true); then you get the resposnse in array format. get the required value.

Comment: `$result->ShippingDeliveryVO->shippingDeliveryDetailVO->operationMessage;`

Comment: You can call from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's so simple..

```
echo $result->ShippingDeliveryVO->shippingDeliveryDetailVO->operationMessage;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$operationMessage = $result->ShippingDeliveryV0->shippingDeliveryDetailV0->operationMessage;
```